# How can i ensure a plot has a specific size when printed?

Tags: plot, latex

I have to create a plot that needs to be standardized in order to fit with a norm.
To present results, graphics with a fixed logarithmic scale should have 5 millimeter spacing in x-Direction and 10 mm in y-Direction.

Is there a way for me to ensure this? So far, i've thought about using LaTeX to get my plot on paper with fixed width and height, but i don't know where to start looking.

Has anyone got any experience with this kind of problem or an idea on how to approach this?

Thanks in advance!

---

*(In case you are wondering, we have conducted an acoustic measurement following EN ISO 16283-1, which requires us to create these special plots. I believe this could be done on paper rather easy, but I'd like to have digital results which I can change at any point.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best LaTeX plots are made with `pgfplots` or `tikz`

I think there's a good bit of help for your question in the `tikz` doc [Manual for Package
pgfplots](http://www.bakoma-tex.com/doc/latex/pgfplots/pgfplots.pdf) (p. 13 - 17)